# Playing wmv in php - blank screen shown in browser

Tags: php, html, windows-media-player, wmv

Let me introduce myself as a newbie in php. I have a requirement to play wmv in a php file.

I try to play a wmv file in php using the following code. But the browser shows a blank white page.

I do not understand why this does not work. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php
$p="<html>\n
<head>\n
<title>My Windows media video webpage file written with PHP</title>\n
</head>\n
<body>\n
<BR>\n
<center><div>Windows media video webpage file written by a PHP page. How do you like it?<BR>\n
<object id=\"MediaPlayer\" classid=\"clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95\"   width=\"480\" height=\"406\" standby=\"Loading Windows Media Player components…\" type=\"application/x-oleobject\" codebase=\"http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls  /mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112\">
<param name=\"FileName\" value=\"ez-architect.wmv\">
<param name=\"AutoStart\" value=\"true\">
<param name=\"ShowControls\" value=\"true\">
<param name=\"BufferingTime\" value=\"2\">
<param name=\"ShowStatusBar\" value=\"true\">
<param name=\"AutoSize\" value=\"true\">
<param name=\"InvokeURLs\" value=\"false\">
<param name=\"AnimationatStart\" value=\"1\">
<param name=\"TransparentatStart\" value=\"1\">
<param name=\"Loop\" value=\"0\">
<embed type=\"application/x-mplayer2\" src=\"ez-architect.wmv\" name=\"MediaPlayer\"  autostart=\"1\" showstatusbar=\"1\" showdisplay=\"1\" showcontrols=\"1\" loop=\"0\" videoborder3d=\"0\" pluginspage=\"http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/\"     width=\"480\" height=\"406\"></embed>
</object>
</div></center>\n
</body>\n
</html>\n";
$a = fopen("my_Windows_media_video_webpage_file_written_with_php.html", 'w');
fwrite($a, $p);
fclose($a);
chmod("my_Windows_media_video_webpage_file_written_with_php.html", 0644);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a sample HTML code for playing WMV videos :

```
<object id="mp3" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" height="240"
type="application/x-oleobject" width="320">
<PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="sunpeek2.wmv">
<PARAM NAME="SendPlayStateChangeEvents" VALUE="False" />
<PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="False" />
<PARAM name="uiMode" value="mini" />
</object>
```